# How can I solve this clear off inconsistency in Firefox and IE7?

Tags: html, css

When I am clearing an element in Firefox4,it goes to the next line leaving some spacing in between and in IE7, it goes to the next line without leaving any space..

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
#a{border:#000 thin groove;float:left;}
#b{border:#000 thin groove;float:left;clear:left;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p id="a">Testing</p>
<p id="b">Testingb</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't half ask a lot of questions! You should try putting more effort into working them out yourself. They seem to be mostly straightforward ones which you could work out by searching and/or using Firebug in Firefox, and the Developer Tools or whatever they call them in IE and Webkit browsers and Dragonfly in Opera.

Comment: So the question is "what's your question?" Do you want to know why it happens or how to get it with/without space all the time? Just posing the problem is one part, but you must also state what is it that you intend/want to get :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most browsers now have a default `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` greater than zero for `p` elements. Internet Explorer doesn't.

Adding `p { margin: 0; }` to your styles will fix it.